# Detecting camera phone parameters

Tags: android, list, flash, parameters, camera

I have created a possible way so i can detect which parameter fits each phone with a simple list. Although right now when i run it crushes,

`public void turnOn() {`

on this line: `List<String> flashMods = params.getSupportedFlashModes();`

```
                 if (flashMods.contains(android.hardware.Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO)) {

                    params = mCamera.getParameters();
                    params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO);
                    mCamera.setParameters(params);
                    mCamera.startPreview();
                    on = true;
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                            "2",
                             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                     if(flashMods.contains(android.hardware.Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON)) {

                        params = mCamera.getParameters();
                        params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);
                        mCamera.setParameters(params);
                        mCamera.startPreview();
                        on = true;
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                            "3",
                             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    if(flashMods.contains(android.hardware.Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH)) {

                        params = mCamera.getParameters();
                        params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                        mCamera.setParameters(params);
                        mCamera.startPreview();
                        on = true;

                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                            "4",
                             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                     if(flashMods.contains(android.hardware.Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_RED_EYE)) {

                         params = mCamera.getParameters();
                         params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_RED_EYE);
                         mCamera.setParameters(params);
                         mCamera.startPreview();
                         on = true;
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                            "5",
                             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
            }

    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled the permission "CAMERA"?

Have you assigned the params object - it might be null.

I do it like this (in Mono / C#, not Java I'm afraid):

```
private void SetUpCamera()
    {
        if (m_camera == null)
            m_camera = Android.Hardware.Camera.Open();

        var holder = m_surface.Holder;
        holder.AddCallback(this);
        holder.SetType(Android.Views.SurfaceType.PushBuffers);
        SetCameraDisplayOrientation();
        GetSurfaceSize(m_camera.GetParameters());
        GetFlashModes(m_camera.GetParameters());

    }
```

then:

```
private void GetFlashModes(Android.Hardware.Camera.Parameters parameters)
    {
        IList<String> flashModes = parameters.SupportedFlashModes;

        m_flashModes = new List<string>();

        if (flashModes == null)//not supported
            return;

        foreach (string mode in flashModes)
            m_flashModes.Add(mode);

        if (m_currentMode != null)//mode has been saved, need to set it to this mode
            SetFlashMode(m_currentMode);
        else
            m_currentMode = GetFlashMode();
    }
```

Comment: You might need to enable the FLASHLIGHT permission as well.

Comment: My manifest and my permissions are okay i believe because if i run each and individual of this parameters alone without the array the work fine, but i wanna cover all of the possibilities